# Error expression must have pointer to object type

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int length(char s)
{ int i;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    {}
    printf("%d",i);
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    scanf("%s",s);
    length(s);
    

}
```

I am trying to write a simple program which prints the no. of characters in a string wihtout using strlen but i am getting these error messages which are beyond my scope of understanding as of now.

Comment: `int length(char s)` should be `int length(char s[100])`, you are passing an array , but collecting it in a `char`

Comment: If you declare a function to return an int you have to return an int.

Comment: `int length(char s)` -> `void length(char const* s)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initiated your function as `Integer`, you should return any argument in the function `length`. But also you print something of length function then you should use function as `void`

```
#include<stdio.h>

void length(char *s)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){}
    printf("%d",i);
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    scanf("%s",s);
    length(s);
    return 0;

}
```

Furthermore, You pass just a character array and you run a loop for the character that's why it showing an exception. If you want you to alive your function as integer then pass a character array like,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int length(char *s)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){}
    printf("%d",i);
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    scanf("%s",s);
    length(s);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int length(char s[])
{ int i;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    {}
    printf("%d",i);
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    scanf("%s",s);
    length(s);
    

}`
```

Found my mistake

Comment: `int length(char s[])` is also a mistake. if you are not going to return a value it should be `void  length(char s[])` or `void length(const char* s)`.

Comment: Or add a `return i;`, that would also make it legal.

Comment: i usually return 0 at the end